# How to force MySQL to write temporary tables on disk rather than in memory for specific query?

Tags: mysql

I know there is a way to force MySQL to write all temporary tables on disk rather than in memory by setting big-tables to 1 ( https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_big_tables ) but I want this behavior for specific query. Weather it return low amount of row or big amount of row. I want MySQL to write it into disk. Is there any workaround to achieve this? More specifically, I want to use that table later as cache table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the SQL_BIG_RESULT modifier

> SQL_BIG_RESULT or SQL_SMALL_RESULT can be used with GROUP BY or
>   DISTINCT to tell the optimizer that the result set has many rows or is
>   small, respectively. For SQL_BIG_RESULT, MySQL directly uses
>   disk-based temporary tables if they are created, and prefers sorting
>   to using a temporary table with a key on the GROUP BY elements. For
>   SQL_SMALL_RESULT, MySQL uses in-memory temporary tables to store the
>   resulting table instead of using sorting. This should not normally be
>   needed.
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Comment: when i use this modifier it seems fast but phpmyadmin profiling didn't report to write disk cache even didn't report to write temp cache. have you any idea about the issue of phpmyadmin profiling system?

Comment: when i didn't use that modifier phpmyadmin report "Copying To Tmp Table" and "Copying To Tmp Table On Disk" but when i use that modifier these two report value didn't appeared. but result seem fast than before.

Answer (score 0):

You can set per-session system variables. 
Sample:

```
mysql> SET SESSION big_tables = On;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec);
```